# Unable to use @spring annotations when class object is new

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Actually i am having a spring main class as follows.

```
ClassLoader loader = null;

    try {
        loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{new   

 File(plugins + "/" + pluginName + "/" + pluginName +   

 ".jar").toURI().toURL()}, getClass().getClassLoader());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 Class<?> clazz = null;

    try {

        clazz = Class.forName("com.sample.Specific", true, loader);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

Method method = null;
    try {
        method = clazz.getMethod("run",new Class[]{});
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 try {
        method.invoke(clazz.newinstance,new Object[]{});
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Specific Class is follow :

```
package com.sample
@Service
public class Specific {

    @Autowired
    private FD fd;


    public void run(){

        fd.init();

    }

}
```

`@Autowired` `FD` comes to be null. Can anyone give me some solution as i also know new operator will not work for `@autowired`. As i am loading class with new instance then only it becomes null. Can anyone guide me in this thing

Comment: Don't use the new operator and inject the Specific class where you need it. If you want to run something immediately after the Spring Boot application is started, have a look at the interface `ApplicationRunner`.

Comment: @dunni -  Actually i am loading class using java reflection in which i have to create the new instance. So, it makes the new instance and make autowired fd null. This code act like an example for us.

Comment: Then you should post an example, which reflects your situation better.

Comment: @dunni - Thanks, I had updated this example

Comment: Do you have control how the Specific class looks like and in what package it is? If so, it would be enough to just let it implement ApplicationRunner and annotate it with `@Component`, then the run method would be automatically called on application startup. That would achieve the same as you do, just without all this reflection stuff

Comment: @dunni - Specific class is present in one of the jar. And i load that jar at runtime and specify the classname when ever i load it at runtime . After loading it runtime when i invoke the run method with new instance the autowired attributes are null.

Comment: So, the thing is basically i have to load this jar at runtime using reflection. Or you have any other way that could load the jar in Spring boot at runtime

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot already does class path scanning and detects beans etc. So if you can change the Specific class because it also belongs to your project, do as i wrote in my last comment and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @dunni for your help. One more thing it created one more issue as :Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: @ Entity @ Table(name = "fddomain") public class FDDomain { @ Id @ Column(name = "name") public String name; @ Column(name = "creationtime") public String creationTime; }

Comment: Please post a new question with all necessary details.

Comment: @dunni -  
Thanks. Actually after creating the ApplicationContext , it says to create the bean for Specific class where it has load. So, how can we create the bean of that

Comment: @dunni - Any updates on my question ?

Comment: If you have more questions or problems, create a new question post here and add all relevant details.

Comment: @dunni https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115102/how-to-create-a-bean-at-runtime-at-the-time-while-using-class-loading-java-refl

Comment: @dunni - Here it is . Thanks For your cooperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring has its own way to provide you new objects. As long as you're consistent using `@Autowired` and `@Component/@Service/@Repository/@Controller` there should be no problem

And since all "business" object instantiation is handled by Spring you should never use `new`. If you have no other way of getting an instance (something I realy doubt about it) you can use [`ApplicationContext.getBean()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-) but as I said, in most cases this is not required (and this is also a bad practice)

If you need several instances of a class instead of injecting them (by using `@Autowired`) you can inject a `Provider<T>`

**UPDATE**

Since the class is known at runtime you need to inject an `ApplicationContext` and use it to get the bean:

```
public class TheClassWhereYouAreCreatingTheObject {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;                  // You definitely need this

    public void theMethodWhereYouAreCreatingTheObject() {
         Class<?> clazz = ...                            // getting the object class
         Object instance = context.getBean(clazz);     // getting and instance trough Spring

         // If you know that kind of object you will get cast it at call its methods
         ((Specific) instance).run();

         // If you know anything about the class you will have to use reflection
         Method method = clazz.getMethod("run", new Class[]{});
         method.invoke(instance, new Object[]{});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pelocho for your suggestions. As i am loading the class at runtime in spring boot, i am also not able to get that field . So, there is no other way to load the class

Comment: I think you have seen the updated example at top. Thanks

Comment: If you're "creating" the instance at runtime consider using `Provider` or injecting the `applicationContext`. If you know at compile time what kind of object it will be use the first approach (it's safer). If the kind of object is known at runtime (and the possibilites are huge) use the second approach

Comment: Actually the thing is i dont know what type of object will be there. I am loading the class at run time and create its new instance. After wards i invoke it methods using the new instance and its paramter. So, when i call that method autowired fields come to be null

Comment: If you use the `newInstance` method you are not using the Spring framework so, obviously, Spring is not injecting anything in the `@Autowired` attributes. Use instead the `getBean()` approach! I will update my answer with more info

Comment: Yeah !. I am doing like you are suggesting. I had done with getbean and also use the Provider<T> but still the field is null.

Comment: But if you use `Provider` the class is known at compile time! You said earlier that the class wasn't known until runtime

Comment: Thanks Pelocho for your help. One more thing it created one more issue as :Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:
@ Entity
@ Table(name = "fddomain")
public class FDDomain {

    @ Id
    @ Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @ Column(name = "creationtime")
    public String creationTime;
}

Comment: That's a totally different issue. If you want to use Hibernate your entities must have a no arguments constructor. Add it and your issue should be solved. However, I'm not sure you're using it correctly. You shouldn't instantiate DB objects like that

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you again. I have one question, as Specific class is not in my current project that is a different project and class loading runs in different project. So, now the thing is when i will load that class using ApplicationContext , then it will ask for bean of Specific class. So, what can we do in that case ?

Comment: The question you posted has been solved. Consider marking the answer as correct and since you have a new issue create a new question

Comment: @Pelco . Thanks For your help . Here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115102/how-to-create-a-bean-at-runtime-at-the-time-while-using-class-loading-java-refl

Comment: Can you please help me out in this question ? As it is coming because of @ ApplicationContext only when  same instance is used

Comment: @Pelco - Can you please help me out in this ?

Comment: @Pelco - Can you send me example of Provider how we can use it

Answer (score 0):

Add Specific Service bean inside your main class. As long as the service is inside one your component scan packages then you shall be fine.  Do not use new operator.

```
@Autowired
private Specific specific;
```

Comment: I agree but i had changed example with specific problem now. Can you help me out in this

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you help me out in this question. This is also same issue as like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115102/how-to-create-a-bean-at-runtime-at-the-time-while-using-class-loading-java-refl

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take advantage of autowiring then I think we have to think from spring terms.

you can use **Beanutils**  to create a new instance and play with reflections supporting spring features.
Please go through below methods:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you help me out in this question please. It is related to same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115102/how-to-create-a-bean-at-runtime-at-the-time-while-using-class-loading-java-refl