# How to create a bean at runtime at the time while using class loading, java reflection and application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a two different project. First Project which consists of a class which loads the plugin and one main class which starts our proejct . In Second Project i have the plugin which is loaded by first project . So, here it is my class loading class :

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

ClassLoader loader = null;

try {
loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{new   

File(plugins + "/" + pluginName + "/" + pluginName +   

".jar").toURI().toURL()}, getClass().getClassLoader());

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

Class<?> clazz = null;

try {

clazz = Class.forName("com.sample.Specific", true, loader);

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

Method method = null;
try {
method = clazz.getMethod("run",new Class[]{});
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
method.invoke(context.getBean(clazz),new Object[]{});
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now i have a plugin in in second project which i am performing some work which is as follow :

```
package com.sample
@Service
public class Specific {

@Autowired
private FD fd;


public void run(){

    fd.init();

}

}
```

Now the thing i am getting is when i add the dependency of Specific class in the main project it starts working fine because it gets the bean of the class Specific. When, i remove the dependency it says that

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.sample.Specific' in your configuration.
```

I dont want to add the dependency as i have to load the class at runtime and start it as it without creating a new instance. Can anyone help me out in this situation please.

Comment: How often are you going to ask the same question. The same has been asked, by you, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095635/unable-to-use-spring-annotations-when-class-object-is-new) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109775/unable-to-create-bean-while-loading-class-at-runtime). Asking the same question every 12 hours isn't going to get you an answer any faster.

Comment: Sorry for that ... M. Deinum . The thing is basically the different. Dont make the questions duplicate without understanding them.

Comment: People There have posted me to ask the new one question. So i posted the new question .